# Ant -e just for the java task

Tags: java, emacs, ant, task

So I know you can pass -e to ant and you won't get the [javac] type tags when ant runs, however I don't want to remove all the tags from the different running portions, just the Java task portion.  Is there an attribute I can set just for the java task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a custom logger that respects the emacs mode for some targets but not others.  That logger can then be passed to ant via -logger.  See the ant documentation on [loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can toss this at the top of your `<target>` block to enable EmacsMode for a single target.

```
<script language="javascript">
  var logger = project.getBuildListeners().firstElement();
  logger.setEmacsMode(true);
</script>
```